# xtext Format comment with AbstractFormatter2,

Tags: xtext

I am using AbstractFormatter2 with xtext 2.9.2

I want to put the comment in a specific column

My syntax looks something like this

```
terminal SL_COMMENT : '*' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;
```

So far, I tried to put multiple spaces before my comment, but this doesn't work either

```
def dispatch void format(Model model, extension IFormattableDocument document) {
    SL_COMMENTRule.prepend[space "         "]
    model.getEnte.format;
    model.getMapset.format;
}
```

can anyone guide my how to format comments in general then how to put them in a specific column

Answer (score 0):

comment formatting is done by commentreplacers

thus something like the following should work

```
    override createCommentReplacer(IComment comment) {
    val EObject grammarElement = comment.getGrammarElement();
    if (grammarElement instanceof AbstractRule) {
        val String ruleName = grammarElement.getName();
        if (ruleName.startsWith("SL")) {
            if (comment.getLineRegions().get(0).getIndentation().getLength() > 0) {
                return new SinglelineDocCommentReplacer(comment, "//") {

                    override configureWhitespace(WhitespaceReplacer leading, WhitespaceReplacer trailing) {
                        leading.getFormatting().space = "            ";
                    }

                };

                } else {
                    return new SinglelineCodeCommentReplacer(comment, "//") {
                        override configureWhitespace(WhitespaceReplacer leading, WhitespaceReplacer trailing) {
                        leading.getFormatting().space = "            ";
                    }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    super.createCommentReplacer(comment)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine, can you please give me a hint on how to put the comment in a specific column number instead of a fixed number of white spaces